# Can't figure out why 'visited style' is not applying to link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Have a link "a" item with a class of "about" and I am trying to create a visited style of purple. But for some reason it is not styling to the 'visited' style. THANK YOU!

```
**html**

<header>
  <a href="about.html" class="about">ABOUT</a>
</header>

**css**

 a {  
  font-family: Gothic A1;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

about a:visited {
 color: purple;
}
 

**hover animation**

a.about {
  position: relative;
}

a.about:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0px;
  background: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a.about:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `a.about:visited`, not `about a:visited`.

`about a` looks for all anchor tags that are children of the `about` element.  `a.about` looks for all anchor tags with the `about` class.

```css
 a {  
  font-family: Gothic A1;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

a.about:visited {
 color: purple;
}
 

a.about {
  position: relative;
}

a.about:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0px;
  background: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a.about:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="about.html" class="about">ABOUT</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi! For some reason that is not working either (maybe due to the hover transition animation - it is like a moving underline)? I might just post the entire portfolio instead. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Hannah Are you sure the url in the `href` attribute exists? It works for me.